# Find the distance between the line and plane

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the distance between the line $x-z=3, x+2y+4z=6$ and the plane $3x+2y+2z=5$.

What I have done so far,

Found the vector by crossing $1,0-1$ and $1,2,4$ from the first line

The line is parallel to plane $\langle 2,-5,2\rangle \cdot \langle 3,2,2 \rangle = 0$

I think my next step is to find a point on Line 1 which satisfies both equations and then insert those values into the plane $3(x)+2(y)+2(z)=5$ and use the formula, $$
\frac{(3(x)+2(y)+2(z)-5)}{(3^2+2^2+2^2)}$$ to find the distance.

The values that I calculuate do not match the posted answer of $7/\sqrt{17}$

Comment: Looking at your question again, I am not sure that I understand what the line is. It looks like your "line" is given by the equations of two *planes*.

Comment: @Thomas any we can descibe lines as intersections of non-parallel planes

Comment: @Norbert: Sure, I just wasn't sure that that was what the OP meant...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The line and the plane (as you have noted) are parallel. The distance from the plane to the line is therefore the distance from the plane to *any point* on the line. So just pick any point on the line and use ["the formula"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane) to find the distance from this point to the plane.

Comment: Thanks, I just made a simple mathematical error which resulted in an incorrect answer.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

If $z=t,$  for the given line $x=z+3=t+3$ and

$x+2y+4z=6$ or, $t+3+2y+4(t)=6$ or, $2y=3-5t$

So, any point on the given line is $(t+3,t,\frac{3-5t}2)$

The distance of $(t+3,t,\frac{3-5t}2)$ from $3x+2y+2z=5$ is $$\left|\frac{3(t+3)+(3-5t)+2(t)-5}{\sqrt{3^2+2^2+2^2}}\right|=\frac 7{\sqrt {17}}$$

Had it not been a constant(which is due to the parallelism), we had to find $t$such that the distance is minimum.

Comment: But if a line is not parallel to a plane, then they intersect and so distance = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Put $(P_1): x - z -3 = 0$, $(P_2): x+2y+4z=6$, $(P_3): 3x + 2y +2z -5 = 0$ and $\Delta$ is intersection of two plane $(P_1)$ and $(P_2)$. We have, a normal vector of the plane $(P_1)$ is $a = (1,0,-1)$, a normal vector of the plane $(P_2)$ is $b = (1,2,4)$. A direction vector $v$ of $\Delta$ is cross product of $a$ and $b$, therefore $v = (3, 2, 2)$. Another way, $M=(3, \dfrac32, 0)$ lies on $\Delta$ and not belongs to $(P_3)$, thus $\Delta$ is parallel to the plane $(P_3)$. We have, the distance between the line $\Delta$ to the plane $(P_3)$ is the distance from the point $M$ to the plane $(P_3)$. From here, we have answer is $$\dfrac{|3\cdot 3 + 2\cdot\dfrac{3}{2} + 2\cdot 0 - 5|}{\sqrt{3^2 + 2^2 + 2^2}} = \dfrac{7\sqrt{17}}{17}.$$